# How much information from ontology we need to export to our home made ontology?

Tags: ontology, wordnet

I'm creating an ontology that is based on wordnet. I want to know what level of information I should add to my own ontology? Like, for example, if the lexica has a "instance of" and "hypernym" relation, do I need to import all this in my ontology? or it's ok to just refer to the lexica in my ontology and use namespace of wordnet as a reference?

Note that I've a list of terms that I want to somehow link to wordnet so these terms make sense.

Comment: It depends on the problem you're trying to solve. When linked "terms make sense" to your application problem? Example would help.